# Find minimum variance & C.R.L.B?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, order-statistics

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, ... , $X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution having mean µ and
variance $σ^2$. Also, Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$, ... , $Y_m$ be a second random sample from the same
distribution that is independent from the first sample.

A. Under what condition(s) on a and b is $W_1$ = $a\bar{X} + b\bar{Y}$
an unbiased estimator for µ?

B. Assuming your condition(s) in part a are met, what values of a and b
make Var($W_1$) a minimum? (Hint: do this directly using the tools of calculus.)

C. Let n = 6 and m = 8. If $W_1$ = $a\bar{X} + b\bar{Y}$ is the unbiased estimate from part b which
 has the minimum variance, find the relative efficiency of $W_1$ with respect to $W_2$ = $\frac{\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{2}$

So far, for  A. I solved for the expected value of $W_1$ and got E($W_1$) = a$\mu$ + b$\mu$. The conditon that needs to be met is that $ a+b=1$ or $ b = 1 - a$. Assuming that is right, for B. my problems start when trying to take the Var($W_1$). My issue is that even though the I can substitute $1-a$ for $b$ the $b$ portion is still over m an not n. Therefore when I try to take the derivatives in terms of $a$ the m is still limiting what I can cancel out and I can't get it to work out so that the second derivative is greater. Am I even headed down the right path? The use your calculus tools hint isn't very specific so I'm not sure how far to take it since I imagine that I'm suppose use the C.R.L.B at some point.

This is my first post so forgive me if my formatting is off, or didn't put enough details. I really am lost though so thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So, what expression do you get for $Var(W_1)$?  I assume the samples are all i.i.d.

Comment: If you do the expression correctly, you get a function of $a$, and you can take the derivative to find the optimal $a$ value.  No need for anything fancy like a Cramer-Rao bound.  As a sanity check, it is intuitively clear that you should put more weight on the one with more samples.

Comment: Var($W_1$)= $\frac{a^2}{n}$ $\sigma^2_1$ + $\frac{1-a^2}{m}$ $\sigma^2_2$

Comment: What is $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$?  I thought these had the same distribution.  Also, are you sure about the $1-a^2$ term?

Comment: Well I interpreted it as same but independent, and therefore different subscripts. I actually meant $(1-a)^2$.

Comment: That is what I get (except I use $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$).  So, can you take a derivative with respect to $a$ and set the result to 0?

Comment: Actually I think I might of copied the format from a similar example and now that I think of it I used only one $\mu$ so I don't know why I am using two $\sigma$'s.

Comment: Doing  as suggested I get $a = \frac{n}{m+n}$ and a second derivative of 2$\sigma^2$$(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m})$ but that isn't always greater then a. So how exactly do I show that a is the min variance? Am I making a computational error?

Comment: Why do you want the second derivative to be larger than $a$?

Comment: The second derivative is positive making the point at which the first derivative is zero a minimum of the original function

Comment: Dude read thru the whole chain of comments without a single thumbs up. Just sayin.

Comment: Thank you Henry. I was mistaken that it had to be larger then a for a to be the minimum.

Comment: Wait, what? How do you thumbs up?

Comment: I was talking to Henry, who seems to know. I think you need a certain level of points first to give a thumbs up.  I was just surprised he read through all our comments but didn't seem to like what I was saying.

Comment: @Michael: Why not change your comments into an answer?

Comment: @Henry Okay, thanks for the suggestion, I have done that now.